# nginx serving some PHP URLs as downloads instead of executing

Tags: php, nginx

Some PHP URLs are being downloaded instead of executed by Nginx.  I have an existing web application which is functioning fine.  I'm tasked with adding additional mounted applications within folders of the primary application.  Each of these applications has its own front controller `index.php` script.

For this setup, I've created symlinks inside `$document_root/app`, and the symlinks point to a folder containing an `index.php` front controller.

When I navigate to most URLs, everything works fine, the primary application front controller is executed, and I get expected results.  When I navigate to a non-existent app, I get `404 Not Found` from nginx, which is expected.  But when I navigate to one of the applications, the browser downloads the application front controller.

```
root                    /my/web/root;

location / {
    try_files           $uri
                        /$server_name$uri
                        /shared$uri
                        /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    disable_symlinks    off;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php\b)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param       SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_param       PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
    fastcgi_index       index.php;
    include             fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass        php-fpm;
}

location ~ ^/app/([a-z-]+)(/.*)?$ {
    try_files           $uri
                        /app/$1/index.php$is_args$args
                        =404;
}
```

**URL which triggers download:** `/app/my-app/` *(exists)*
**URL which 404s:** `/app/foo/` *(does not exist)*
**URL which executes:** `/foo`

Comment: Try to set location for php to `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.php` file needs to be processed by the `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` block. You have a common document root which makes things simpler.

However, [look at this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) regarding the `location` directive.

You will see that the regex locations are considered **in order** and the first matching location will be used to process the request.

In short, you need to place the `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` block **before** any other conflicting regex location, if you want your `.php` files to be processed correctly.

Comment: No change in behavior.  Explicit `.../app/index.php` URL executes, implicit `.../app/` URL downloads, non-app URLs execute.

Comment: You have an error in your last `try_files` directive. Remove the `=404`. The `/app/$1/index.php$is_args$args` element must be last on the line. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: More on why `=404` breaks things: [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) serves “the first found file” from its list “in the current context”. For `/app/my-app`, that context is the `location ~ ^/app/([a-z-]+)(/.*)?$` block, which doesn’t handle PHP — so nginx sends out the raw `/app/my-app/index.php` source file. However, the last item in a try_files list is *redirected* to. When `/app/$1/index.php` is last, it’s redirected to the `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|S)` block, which does handle PHP — so after removing `=404`, the my-app front controller runs.